# HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Im trying to create a HABTM association between my products and tags tables. I ran the automated migration in my terminal as:

```
rails generate migration create_products_tags_join_table
```

then

```
rake db:migrate
```

After I ran those commands I assumed that my migration file would look something like what I read on the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html But instead my migration file looks like this

```
class CreateProductsTagsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
  end

  def down
  end
end
```

Do I need to hard code in the migration within these methods and then run the `rake db:migrate` command again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are way's you can name your migration to get the migration auto generate definition tags but I just do these types of things manually.

In your Case you need 3 tables:

- products
- tags
- products_tags (alphabetical order matters here.  This is your join table).

## Products Table Migration

```
class CreateProductsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      # whatever you want here...
    end
  end
end
```

## Tags Table Migration

```
class CreateTagsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tags do |t|
      # whatever you want here...
    end
  end
end
```

## Join Table Migration

```
class CreateProductsTagsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products_tags , :id => false, force: true do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :tag_id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrew I'll manually write the join in the migration file. Just curious do you know what the commands would be auto generate the definition tags into the migration file?

Comment: i think these 3 commands might do the trick, although i didnt test. "rails g migration CreateTagsTable product:references", "rails g migration CreateProductsTable tag:references", and "rails g migration CreateJoinTableProductsTags product tag". Check the "Creating a Migration" section here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure if you want some stuff filled out, you'd need to generate a model, not a migration.

So, something like:

rails generate model productstags

That generates the following migration file:

20140930204336_create_productstags.rb

class CreateProductstags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :productstags do |t|

```
  t.timestamps
end
```

end
end

You'd need to define any fields either manually here or in the model generation.   But, if you generate a migration you have to define what you're doing.   Like, say I wanted to add a join_id field that is an integer to my new ProductsTags table.

rails g migration add_join_id_to_productstags join_id:integer

That generates the following.

class AddJoinIdToProductstags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :productstags, :join_id, :integer
  end
end

Pretty sure you just need to go that route.